# How to make leaderboard in android game?Is signing in with google account is necessary?

Tags: android, google-play-services

I have a game which does't have leaderboard I want to make leaderboard in my android game.So I have few question.

1) How to make leaderboard in android game?
2)Is signing in with google account is necessary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For question 1: Try Android Code Samples from https://github.com/playgameservices/android-basic-samples

For question 2: Yes, according to my knowledge.

Comment: I have gone through your app Number series.Please help me how to make leaderboard ?

Comment: I followed the steps from https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/quickstart.

Comment: Thanks It was really helpful

Comment: Also, you can check this tutorial https://www.myandroidsolutions.com/2017/11/02/android-add-game-leaderboard/#.Wft6AdCWbIV if you still encounter problems.